# git am is choking characters from my commit messages

Tags: git, format-patch, git-am

I'm using some private annotations in my git commit messages.

For example, when I fixed something in module `MOD_A`, the commit message looks like this:

```
FIX [MOD_A] Fixed something
```

As long as there's `FIX` in front of `[MOD_A]`, everything works fine if I generate a patch using

```
git format-patch
```

send this patch as attachment to somewhere and then use

```
git am --keep-cr *.patch
```

in order to store this commit in another repo.

**But:** If I don't have `FIX` in front of `[MOD_A]` (i.e. `[MOD_A] Fixed something`), the start of the message is missing in the other repo after doing `git am`. The whole commit message is only `Fixed something`.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the format of the **Subject** line of the E-Mail generated by `git format-patch`:

```
Subject: [PATCH 23/27] [MOD_A] Fixed something
```

It seems like because the `[PATCH 23/27]` is enclosed in squared brackets, also `[MOD_A]` is ignored.

Is there a way to have my `[MOD_A]` **not** ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can live without `[PATCH x/x]` automatically added to subject line,
you could do [`git format-patch -k`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and then [`git am -k ...`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html)

i assume just pushing your patches to another repo is not an option

Comment: I can **definetly** live without it. Great hint!.

Answer (score 5):

With git as version '1.8.4' (perhaps before) you can also use: `git am --keep-non-patch`. It passes the `-b` flag to `git mailinfo`:

> -b
>
> ```
>        When -k is not in effect, all leading strings bracketed with [ and ] 
>        pairs are stripped. This option limits the stripping to only the pairs
>        whose bracketed string contains the word "PATCH".
> ```

Emanuele